# Laravel website refusing to display an image searched in the app/public folder

Tags: php, laravel

Here is the problem: I would like to display images located in the app/public folder in the browser.
The algorithm is as such:
1-Get the reference;
2-Look for every file having that name in app/public and its subfolders;
3-Display every of them in the blade file.

Here is inside my blade file:

```
<div class="py-16">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            
                @foreach($matchingFiles as $file)
                    <!--<img src="{{asset('storage/'.$file->getPathname()) }}" alt="{{$file->getFilename() }}">-->
                    <img src="{{ asset('dossiers/' . urlencode($file->getPathname())) }}" alt="{{ $file->getFilename() }}">
                @endforeach`
```

Here is what is inside my controller:

```
public function consult($id){
        $tableData=alignement::find($id);
        $reference=$tableData->reference;
        $directory=storage_path("app/public/dossiers");
        $contents=File::allFiles($directory);
        $matchingFiles=[];

        foreach($contents as $file){
            if(strpos($file->getFilename(),$reference) !==false){
                $matchingFiles[]=$file;
            }
        }
        return view('displayFolder',['matchingFiles'=>$matchingFiles]);
    }
```

The results: It actually detects the images but only returns broken images icons for every file detected. What should I do?

At first, the files were in app/dossiers, but I moved them to app/public/dossiers in the hope that it does display correctly.

Comment: Your server side code has permission to access the image file, but not the web side. Check the url in the browser, and the permission of your image file.

Comment: Share the generated image URL in HTML using DevTools.

Comment: Are you sure `getPathname` is the correct function to use here? I would imagine you'd need to use `getFilename` to get the file name instead of the file path

Comment: Denis Sinyukov asks: *"Are you seaching files in the `storage_path` or in the `public_path`? In blade one in the controller the other"*

Comment: assuming you have linked your storage folder, try: `asset('storage/dossiers/' . urlencode($file->getFilename()))`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure that your `app/public` is accessible from web by running `php artisan storage:link` in cmd. Make sure that the shortcut folder of *storage* is created in your public folder.

Then, you can do as @kris said in the comment like below.

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/dossiers/' . urlencode($file->getPathname())) }}" alt="{{ $file->getFilename() }}">
```

Make sure the path is like `storage/app/public/dossiers/image.jpg`.

Answer (score -1):

Can you change :
$directory=storage_path("app/public/dossiers");

By :

$directory=public_path("app/public/dossiers");

To try ?